# I want my main url to point to a custom page. Site is wordpress, but page is standalone

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I have a URL that has Wordpress installed on it, but until the site is ready, I'd like it to point to a landing page that I just put up. This page is a Foundation page, with it's own css and js. It's completely independent of the Wordpress site.

I'd like http://denizencomic.com to redirect to http://denizencomic.com/launchingsoon.php

and have spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to do that. Most things I find are just ways to point to other wordpress pages, which is what I don't want to do.

Thank you for your help!

Brookes

Comment: so you want your domain to NOT land on wordpress, but to land on a home page that has content for launchingsoon.php?  then in that page do you want a link to your wordpress site, or are you simply trying to put your wp site in maintenance mode?

Comment: Maintenance mode is probably the key idea. This page will be gone, there's no linking back to the WP site, and at that point there will be no point for this page anymore. Is there perhaps a simpler way than moving the entire directory in that case? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what i mentioned below is actually VERY simple, i have done it several times.  if you can imagine, make a new directory called wp, cut and paste all files into this directory, copy and paste two files back up to the parent (index and ht), then just delete most of what is on the root index.php that you just copied up, and paste your content there. viola,

Comment: alright, working on copying the whole site over at the moment, hopefully it goes smoothly. Thank you!

Comment: lol, also, i added a possible easier solution. see my answer below.  good luck.  be back tomorrow.  If it works for you, please check that answer off as accepted answer if possible :-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried both things, the exit; didn't work and the site move gives me "The requested URL /wp-admin.php was not found on this server." type 404s. It's now officially taken me longer to change one page to a shorter URL than to create it in the first place. This is absolute insanity. Nothing about this resembles simple.

Comment: ok, notice, i said it "might work", which means i suggest you try the first opeion, give wordpress its own subdir.  you started this process, how did that one go?

Answer (score 1):

i think giving wordpress its own subdirectory is what you want.  you want not only wordpress driven content, but also other separate php content to accompany yoru site correct?  the right way to do this is giving wordpress its own directory, then keep your stuff above that, in the site root.   this allows you to separate your content.

see this url
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

that should be all you need, copying the .htaccess, adjust it, copy the index file, moving of your entire wordpress site, including all files into the subdir.

your new index file that is in the root (above the wordpress installation) is where your launchingsoon content goes on.

you can go even further and rename it to launchingsoon.php, then adjust that on the .htaccess so it can find your launchingsoon.php file.  it can treat it as the new index.

There is a simpler way that might work

open the main index.php file in your root, move down the code, put a new php block on top, end it with the command `exit;`  then put your code on top of that exit command.  im sure it will load this way.   you might also want to temporarily rename your .htaccess to htaccess.bak if the index file wont load correctly.